# How do i implement or configure or get an instance of the Gmail in the GMAIL JAVA API when sending an email

Tags: java, gmail

In the method below, how do i get the Gmail instance or how is it implemented or configured in the GMAIL JAVA API? Can some one explain the argument for the first paramater?

```
       public  void sendMessage(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage email)
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample

Answer (score 1):

To get Gmail Instance,import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail in your java class and please download Jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev3-1.18.0-rc.